# this is my code but background of tile which is user control is not getting changed

Tags: wpf, user-controls, background-color

```
<Window x:Class="justTry.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ucl="clr-namespace:justTry" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="LightBlue">

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ucl:tile}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>



    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ucl:tile Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ></ucl:tile>
    <ucl:tile Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></ucl:tile>
    <ucl:tile Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" ></ucl:tile>
    <ucl:tile Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" ></ucl:tile>
    <ucl:tile Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ></ucl:tile>
    <ucl:tile Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" ></ucl:tile>
    <ucl:tile Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ></ucl:tile>
    <ucl:tile Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ></ucl:tile>
    <ucl:tile Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"></ucl:tile>
    <ucl:tile Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
    <ucl:tile Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```

this is my code.code is not giving error but background color is not getting changed
Here tile is my usercontrol and i want to change its background color as it is in windows 8 Metro Ui style.so i want every tile of different color but it is not possible to override background color using style or any thing.give me some suggestion .even i m trying this code it won't give any error but color of user control(tile) won't get changed.
please help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution to ur question.

The problem here is You have to access the content/children of the Windows/Page which you are using as a usercontrol.

Here's the modification that is to be done in the

```
<ucl:tile Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="tile1" ></ucl:tile >
```

name all the usercontrols as tile1, tile2 .....

and from the code behind after initializecomponents in the constructor of the MainWindow
Add the following code for each tile.

```
((Grid)tile.Content).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Here grid has been casted because mostly the content of the usercontrol always start with a grid . you can cast it to any other UIElement like canvas or any thing but should be the same that you have put in the user